# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused - suddenly stopped working

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant

I have a Laravel app that I'm running with Vagrant VM.

It was working fine but then suddenly the page stopped loading and the logs showed this error:

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /home/vagrant/.../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /home/vagrant/.../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27)
[stacktrace]
```

I can still check my database with Sequel Ace, I can still run migrations. I tried halting Vagrant and starting it again, nothing changed.

I checked the memory:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       641Mi       2.5Gi        27Mi       701Mi       3.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
vagrant@homestead:~$ nproc
1
```

I don't know what else to do. It has been working fine for the last 3 months, so I don't think I need to make some changes in the settings file, that is what most solutions were suggesting.

Comment: whats your database configuration? assuming the credentials wasn't change, it could be a port or host issue

Comment: @silver i doubt it's that because it went from working to not working in one second. what configuration should i check?

Comment: Memory in my homestead.yml file is 4096, maybe that has been exceeded?

Comment: It seems like my database had some errors. When I imported db from production it all worked fine

Comment: I had same problem but on production. I think it was caused by lost connection in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

check what port your mysql is using, just run your server

`netstat -tlnp`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10082/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1442/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13412/php-fpm: pool
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1442/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      15889/mysqld
```

make sure your `DB_PORT` on laravel `.env` is having the same port as you see on the output above

also, try changing your `DB_HOST` to `localhost` or if its already using localhost, change it to `127.0.0.1`